# Is it possible to render only procedural stripes material?

Tags: rendering, procedural

I’m a very beginner in Blender. I got two questions about something I’m studying:

1. I got this hand model and applied a stripe material following a YT tutorial. Is it possible to render just the stripes? I tried turning on all I could find in Passes, inside View Layer. I’m using Cycles that seems to be the one that have more Passes options, but when connecting in File Output and rendering it, I couldn’t be able to see just the stripes.
2. Is possible to the stripes don’t deform? I see that is an organic mesh, but when the fingers folds, I was expecting not to simply make that big black spot. I played around the scale setting OS X, Y and Z in Mapping but the best I could was the image I attached.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to bake the stripe material as an image texture?

Comment: If you want only the stripes, connect the _ColorRamp_ to the _Alpha_ of the _Principled BSDF_ (or it's inverse, depending on which color stripes you want to "keep"). The large black spot is because the wave texture exists in 3D space, which your object is passing through at different points depending on it's shape - to get a uniform stripe pattern, you must use UV texture coordinates, but that will require a proper UV unwrap.

Comment: Thank you both. Spot on, Christopher Bennett.